# initialize member array with constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, object, constructor, initialization

I have a class `School` like this. `Space` is an abstract class, don't mind about it.

```cpp
class school:public space
{

    private:
        schoolyard y;

        stairs s;
        floor floors[3];
        int capa;
    public:
        school(int x):floors[1](x),floors[2](x),floors[3](x){
         cout<<"a school has been created"<<endl;}
         void move(student x);
        ~school();

};
```

`floor` is another class which I want to initialize. This part `floors[1](x),floors[2](x),floors[3](x)` is probably wrong. Maybe someone know how I can initialize an array of objects in a class?

Comment: not a fix, but valid indices in an array with 3 elements are `0`,`1` and `2`.

Comment: What do you mean by array of objects in the class? do you mean array of instances of the class?

Answer (score 3):

Should be:

```
school(int x) : floors{x, x, x}
{
    std::cout << "a school has been created" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, arrays are 0-based, so the valid indexes are 0-2, not 1-3.

Second, you can't initialize individual array members in a constructor's [member initialization list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) like you are attempting to.

If `floor` does not have a [default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor), you can change your `floors[]` array to hold `floor*` pointers instead, and then construct each `floor` object using [`new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) in the constructor's body, eg:

```cpp
class school : public space
{
    private:
        ...
        floor* floors[3];
        ...

    public:
        school(int x){
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
                floors[i] = new floor(x);
            }
            // other initialization as needed...
            cout << "a school has been created" << endl;
        }

        ~school(){
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
                delete floors[i];
            }
        }

        ...
};
```

Be aware that with this approach, you need to follow the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), which means also implementing a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator, and optionally a move constructor and a move assignment operation in C++11 and later:

```cpp
...
#include <algorithm>

class school : public space
{
    private:
        ...
        floor* floors[3];
        ...

    public:
        school(int x){
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
                floors[i] = new floor(x);
            }
            // other initializations as needed...
            cout << "a school has been created" << endl;
        }

        school(const school &src){
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
                floors[i] = new floor(*(src.floors[i]));
            }
            // other copies as needed...
            cout << "a school has been copied" << endl;
        }

        school(school &&src){
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
                floors[i] = src.floors[i];
                src.floors[i] = nullptr;
            }
            // other moves as needed...
            cout << "a school has been moved" << endl;
        }

        ~school(){
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
                delete floors[i];
            }
        }

        school& operator=(const school &rhs){
            if (this != &rhs){
                school temp(rhs);
                std::swap_ranges(floors, floors+3, temp.floors);
            }
            return *this;
        }

        school& operator=(school &&rhs){
            school temp(std::move(rhs));
            std::swap_ranges(floors, floors+3, temp.floors);
            return *this;
        }

        ...
};
```

However, a `std::vector` would make things much easier, letting the compiler handle all of these details for you, eg:

```cpp
...
#include <vector>

class school : public space
{
    private:
        ...
        std::vector<floor> floors;
        ...

    public:
        school(int x): floors(3, floor(x)) {
            cout << "a school has been created" << endl;
        }

        ...
};
```